How to use IOUserAudioBooleanControl from AudioDriverKit
I am trying to add an output mute to an AudioDriverKit driver.
I create the control like this:
ivars->m_output_mute_control = IOUserAudioBooleanControl::Create( in_driver, true, true, IOUserAudioObjectPropertyElementMain,
IOUserAudioObjectPropertyScope::Output, IOUserAudioClassID::MuteControl);

The Mute button in Audio Midi Setup starts off as muted, just like I specified in the third parameter, but when it is clicked, the state does not change. It stays muted (See screenshot).
Do I need to publish the new state in some way?

